Maui Image from source in collection view crashes on Android but works on Windows
I'm trying to create a page that loads images remotely from an ObservableCollection. This works fine on Windows but crashes on Android emulator.  I'm using VS 17.11.3.  I read on github that this was a problem on 17.3 but it is supposed to be fixed.  Is this still a known problem?  Any workarounds?
<CollectionView
Grid.Row="4"
ItemsSource="{Binding RecommendedList}"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <GridItemsLayout
        HorizontalItemSpacing="5"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        Span="1"
        VerticalItemSpacing="5" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid
            Padding="10,0,10,0"
            ColumnDefinitions="1*,10,Auto"
            RowDefinitions="Auto"
            RowSpacing="5">
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Aspect="Center">
                <Image.Source>
                    <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding ImgUrl}" />
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
            <Label
                Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

Edit 1
The C# code supplying the link is the cause of the error - System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Connection failure'
The associated call stack is
    0x11 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw    C#
    0x3E in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess  C#
    0x2E in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification C#
    0xA in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd  C#
    0x7 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.GetResult   C#
>   0x37A in Library.LibraryService.GetRecommmendedReads at C:\Users\richa\source\repos\LibraryAppM\Class1.cs:374,25    C#
    0x11 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.Recommended>>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Library.LibraryService.<GetRecommmendedReads>d__61>.ExecutionContextCallback  C#
    0x42 in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal   C#
    0x47 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.Recommended>>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Library.LibraryService.<GetRecommmendedReads>d__61>.MoveNext  C#
    0x2 in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Collections.Generic.List<Library.Recommended>>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Library.LibraryService.<GetRecommmendedReads>d__61>.MoveNext   C#
    0x6 in System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0    C#
    0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19 C#
    0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:37,6 C#
    0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4    C#
    0x8 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:22,5  C#

This is shown on github.com - https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1260 but should be solved. I've checked the uri's in question and they are all correct.

"read on github" - can you supply the link?  Are you sure its the ImageSource that causes the problem?  Can you capture the exception causing the crash?

It was https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6295

As it's Android, I'm not sure how to capture the exception.

VS should break and show you the exception and stack trace

There's something amiss with my VS as it never breaks or shows the exception details. The best I can do is use try catch and debug.write.

I do have the tick for common exceptions but it makes no difference

Did the image's link start with http no https? Android doesn't support http link default.

I've changed the design to exclude the image file.
